# Error "The script failed due to call depth overflow" during execution of PowerShell script

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script which test if two folders exists and if no folders than create new one. Problem is when I try to execute script I get "The script failed due to call depth overflow" error. Also I would like to put two conditions in one if - if folder 1 and folder 2 don't exist than create folder 1 and folder 2 - else - write folders exists. And (if it's possible) I would like to somehow check - so if folder 1 exists than create only folder 2 and write - folder 1 exists!

```
# Start script recording

Start-Transcript

# Variable which is path to future/existing PowerShell log folder

$ptsl = "$($env:HOMEDRIVE)\VL\Win_mult_machines"

# Variable which is path of future/existing Vagrant folder

$ptvf = "$($env:HOMEDRIVE)\VM\Win_mult_machines"

# Variable which is future/existing name of log and Vagrant folders

$lvn = "Win_mult_machines"

# Test path for script log - if path doesn't exist - create it

if (-Not (Test-Path $ptsl -PathType Container))

      {
       New-Item -Path "$($env:HOMEDRIVE)\VL\" -Name $lvn -ItemType Directory      
      }

 else {
         Write-Output "Folder already exists!"
      }

# Test path for Vagrant box folder - if path doesn't exist - create it

 if (-Not (Test-Path $ptvf -PathType Container))

      {
       New-Item -Path "$($env:HOMEDRIVE)VB\" -Name $lvn -ItemType Directory
      }

 else {
       Write-Output "Folder already exists!"
      }
```

Comment: This does not appear to be the entire script; you are using variables that are never defined (`$ptsl` and `$ptvf`). Please either include the entire script (and tell us the file name), or reduce the script to a minimal standalone script that reproduces the problem.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin Script is not finished yet. I have edited original post and put everything which I have for now.

Comment: Your code as shown works for me, but the error you are seeing suggests you are trying to do something recursively beyond the maximum permitted call depth. Is there any recursion in your larger script?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is causing your issue, but there is a typo in your code:

```
   New-Item -Path "$($env:HOMEDRIVE)VB\" -Name $lvn -ItemType Directory
```

Should be:

```
   New-Item -Path "$($env:HOMEDRIVE)\VB\" -Name $lvn -ItemType Directory
```

The error you are seeing suggests you are trying to do something recursively beyond the maximum permitted call depth (e.g new-item is calling itself more than 100 times).

Answer (score 1):

This is weird PowerShell error - I have reloaded PowerShell ISE and issue is gone.

Comment: The thing about PowerShell ISE is that it seems to save variables between script executions. If your script references a variable $foo but $foo has not been defined in the current execution, but it was defined in a previous execution, then it will still have the value from that previous execution.